Create a script that would rotate a wheel around it's Z axis in Unity VR
For the past week I have been trying to create the script of a wheel in Unity that is supposed to rotate only on the Z axis. You should be able to grab the wheel and it would follow your hand, let go, and grab again from a different point without affecting it's current rotation.
public class LookAtScript_v2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Testing vars.
    [SerializeField]
    TextMeshPro DegreesFromUpToSnapText; // <- Text used for debugging purposes only.

    // Visible attributes.
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform target; // <- Variable that represents the target we're following.

    [SerializeField]
    private bool watchingTheObject = true; // <- Variable that mocks the grabbing and letting go of the object.
    
    [SerializeField]
    [Range(1f, 36f)] // <- Change here the range of snaps if needed (future functionality).
    private int SnapPoints = 1;

    // Background attributes.
        // Variables used for rotating the wheel on one axis without it always snapping towards the hand.
    private float alphaAngle = 0;

    // Let go of the wheel only once tracker
    bool letGo = true;

    void Update()
    {
        if(target != null && watchingTheObject)
        {
            letGo = false;

            Vector2 vectorToTarget = target.position - transform.position;
            // rotatedVector is a vector that points in "the direction of our target" - the angle alpha (angle between our target vector and the direction
            // our wheel is already facing). 
            Vector2 rotatedVector;

            // Calculate the angle alpha only the first time we grab the wheel, afterwards it should be constant
            if (alphaAngle == 0)
            {
                alphaAngle = Vector2.SignedAngle(vectorToTarget, transform.right);
            }
            
            // We use rotatedVector to point in the direction where the x axis is currently looking
            // this allows us to rotate the wheel from its current position, without it always rotating to face our target.
            rotatedVector = Quaternion.AngleAxis(alphaAngle, Vector3.forward) * vectorToTarget;

            // Use transform.right to look in the same direction as our rotatedVector.
            transform.right = rotatedVector.normalized;
        }
        else if(!watchingTheObject && !letGo)
        {
            alphaAngle = 0;
            letGo = true;
        }
    }

    
}

My current problem is the following: The wheel always faces the world Z axis.
I am aware that the reason is me using Vector2, but I couldn't find a way to convert to Vector3 and have it work in the same manner. Could someone help me make the script work for a wheel using its local coordinates?
The goal is to have it rotating it any orientation.
Thank you in advance!
Edit:
Hey guys, I will leave this here. I have tried different ideas and approaches to this problem, and I finally managed to find a code that works - you are able to rotate the wheel around it's Z axis, it respects its previous position when you grab the wheel and let go of it. Also, the wheel works perfectly no matter the orientation of the parent.
For it to work, you need a parent object that will have 2 other objects as children:
• pivot point.
• valve itself.

And here is the script itself in case someone might need it in the future. Took me almost 2 weeks of attempts. =)
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class LookAtScript_v3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform target; // the target the wheel is following, used instead of the VR hand

    [SerializeField]
    private bool watchingTheObject = false; // variable to simulate the grabbing of the wheel and letting go of it without a VR headset

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform pivotPoint; // point that specifies the center of the wheel

    private float alphaAngle = 0; // angle between the current orientatino of the wheel, and the vector that points towards the target
    float newAngle = 0;
    private float previousAngle = 0; // Angle that can be used to check if we are rotating clockwise or counter-clockwise

    private float rotationSpeed = 400f; // self-explanatory

    void Update()
    {
        if(target != null && watchingTheObject)
        {
            UnityEngine.Vector3 vectorToTarget = target.position - pivotPoint.position;
            UnityEngine.Vector3 vectorToTargetLocal = pivotPoint.transform.InverseTransformDirection(vectorToTarget);
            vectorToTargetLocal = UnityEngine.Quaternion.Euler(pivotPoint.rotation.eulerAngles) * vectorToTargetLocal;
            
            if (alphaAngle == 0)
            {
                alphaAngle = UnityEngine.Vector3.SignedAngle(vectorToTargetLocal, transform.up, pivotPoint.forward);
                Debug.LogError("alpha angle is: " + alphaAngle);
            }

            UnityEngine.Vector3 rotatedVectorToTarget = UnityEngine.Quaternion.AngleAxis(alphaAngle, transform.forward) * vectorToTargetLocal;

            // Get the target angle in the local Z axis
            float targetAngle = UnityEngine.Vector3.SignedAngle(pivotPoint.up, rotatedVectorToTarget, pivotPoint.forward);

            Debug.DrawRay(pivotPoint.position, rotatedVectorToTarget, UnityEngine.Color.black);
            Debug.DrawRay(pivotPoint.position, pivotPoint.up, UnityEngine.Color.blue);


            // Get the current angle around the local Z axis
            float currentAngle = transform.localEulerAngles.z;
            Debug.Log("target angle: " + targetAngle);
            Debug.Log("current angle: " + currentAngle);
            
            // Ensure the angles are in the range -180 to 180
            if (currentAngle - alphaAngle > 180) currentAngle -= 360;
            if (targetAngle  - alphaAngle > 180) targetAngle -= 360;
            
            // Rotate towards the target angle smoothly
             newAngle = Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(currentAngle, targetAngle, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            // Apply the new rotation
            transform.localEulerAngles = new UnityEngine.Vector3(0, 0, newAngle);

            previousAngle = newAngle;

        }
        else if(!watchingTheObject)
        {
            alphaAngle = 0;
        }
    }
}



Assuming the rest works as expected - I believe you could use the local Z axis by convert all the positions into local space via Transform.InverseTransformPoint, then calculate in 2D space, then finally convert back to the world space via Transform.TransformDirection
void Update()
{
    if(target != null && watchingTheObject)
    {
        letGo = false;

        Vector2 vectorToTarget = transform.InverseTransformPoint(target.position);
       
        // Calculate the angle alpha only the first time we grab the wheel, afterwards it should be constant
        if (alphaAngle == 0)
        {
            alphaAngle = Vector2.SignedAngle(vectorToTarget, Vector2.right);
        }
        
         // rotatedVector is a vector that points in "the direction of our target" - the angle alpha (angle between our target vector and the direction
        // our wheel is already facing). 
        // We use rotatedVector to point in the direction where the x axis is currently looking
        // this allows us to rotate the wheel from its current position, without it always rotating to face our target.
        var rotatedVector = Quaternion.AngleAxis(alphaAngle, Vector3.forward) * vectorToTarget;

        // Use transform.right to look in the same direction as our rotatedVector.
        transform.right = transform.TransformDirection(rotatedVector.normalized);
    }
    else if(!watchingTheObject && !letGo)
    {
        alphaAngle = 0;
        letGo = true;
    }
}

Instead of using Quaternion you might also want to look into alternatives for rotating a Vector2
